# Capturing analytics Instrumentation events

Tags: android, mixpanel, scalable

We have integrated the mixpanel library in our app for tracking user behaviour. There are literally 1000s of events flowing with multiple properties metadata within each of the events. Recently I was given a task to capture and collate them all in a document and keep it available for everyone to refer to in burning times like prod app going down or some flow in the app is breaking and we want to mitigate the issue.

Right now source code is the only source of truth about these events and we refer it whenever needed.

Moving this to a document with all the details requires lot of manual work. How would you go about solving this problem?

Thanks

I tried manually collating by going thru the code base. But there are more than 1000 events in the app that keeps evolving. Not a scalable solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.